# What is the time complexity of following code

Tags: time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the following code? In the second for loop, j increments j=j*2

```
`int k=0;
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     for(j=1;j<n;j=j*2)
         k=k+1;
 return k;`
```

Answer (score 2):

The two loops are independent, because neither depends on the other.  So, we may express the complexity of the two nested loops as the product of the individual complexities.  In this case, the outer loop in `i` is `O(n)` and the inner loop in `j` is `O(lgn)` (log base 2 of `n`).  So, the overall time is `O(nlgn)`.

To see why the inner loop is `O(lgn)`, consider a value `n` of 16:

```
j  | step#
1  | 1
2  | 2
4  | 3
8  | 4
16 | 5
```

We can see that it took 5 steps to generate 16, which is roughly `lg(16)`.